# LocalizedString of DateFormatter is different from iOS default calendar app

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

When I try to get the `localizedString` from `DateFormatter`, the output is different from the format that the iOS default calendar app shows.

`DateFormatter` for US Locale shows (for dateStyle full)

> Tuesday, August 15, 2017

where iOS default calendar app shows

> Tue, Aug 15, 2017

`DateFormatter` for KR Locale shows (for dateStyle full)

> 2017년 8월 15일 화요일

where iOS default calendar app shows

> 2017년 8월 15일 (화)

How do I get the `localizedString` as shown in the iOS default calendar app? Should I create custom format for all the locale?

Comment: Try `.medium` instead of `.full` for the date style.

Comment: But medium will not show the week of day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the standard styles show an abbreviated weekday and month name.

One option would be to use `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate`.

```
let df = DateFormatter()
df.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("EEEMMMddyyyy")
let string = df.string(from: Date())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("EEE, MMM dd, yyyy")
print(formatter.string(from: Date()))
```

Comment: 1. This is simply a copy of my answer. 2. There is no need to put punctuation in the template. It is ignored.